# What is the algorithm to calculate the RGB output for Photoshop's color levels?

Tags: rgb, photoshop, pixel

In Photoshop, I used the "color level option" tool to modify the RGB pixel (84, 90, 123) to various color levels. The RGB output is:

```
red...... (146,  32,  59)
green.... ( 28, 151,  59)
blue..... ( 28,  32, 177)
yellow... (146, 151,  59)
magenta.. (146,  32, 177)
cyan..... ( 28, 151, 177)
```

What is an algorithm that can be used outside of Photoshop to reproduce this?

Comment: Are you looking for the algorithm that applies a color level to a pixel? Like in your first example: f([84, 90, 123], [255, 0, 0]) = [146, 32, 59]

Comment: yes!! but how to calculate?

Comment: There isn't exactly an algorithm. For example, rgb are the decimal versions of the color. You would simply convert this to hex to use it for the web. For example, #ffffff is really r = 255, g = 255, and b = 255.

Comment: I meant ..I want to know why became [146, 32, 59] ?? ..... [84, 90 , 123][255, 0, 0] I think it needs conversion

Comment: This color shift is probably done in another color space; HSB (straightforward), or possibly L*a*b.